# create each csv row to json file in php

Tags: php, json, csv, fgetcsv, csvtojson

i found this code for csv row as a object

```
$fp = fopen('test.csv','r') or die("**! can't open file\n\n");
$i = 0;
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    $i++;
    $json['json_'.$i]['id'] = $csv_line[0];
    $json['json_'.$i]['product_id'] = $csv_line[1];
    $json['json_'.$i]['title'] = $csv_line[2];
    $json['json_'.$i]['outline'] = $csv_line[3];        
}
$json['total_lines'] = $i;
print json_encode($json);
fclose($fp) or die("**! can't close file\n\n");
```

**how to create each csv row as a separate json file in php**

[image: csv row to json file]

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to make a reasonable effort upfront here - not just to ask “how to”. Show us what you tried please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soultion simplified:

```
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    $json = [
        'id' => $csv_line[0],
        'product_id' => $csv_line[1],
        'title' => $csv_line[2],
        'outline' =>  $csv_line[3],
    ];
    // use any other naming approach that you want
    file_put_contents('file_' . $csv_line[0] . '.json', json_encode($json));
}
```